# Best practice to inject modules in angularJS using browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to simplify my angular application with gulp and browserify. Unfortunately I'm struggling with the concept of require and exports mixed with angulars dependency injection (DI). I have to change a lot of files in order to get the browserify running so I want ro get some things clear before I start.

For example, I have a module moduleAB that contains two factories, each defining a class. FactoryA creates classA and factoryB creates classB. classB inherits from classA. So in my code I have something like:

```
angular.module("moduleAB", [])
    .factory("factoryA", ["$window", function(wndw) {
        return function classA (a, b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        };
    }])
    .factory("factoryB", ["factoryA", function(classA) {

        var classB = function (a, b) {
            classA.call(this, a, b);
        };

        classB.prototype = Object.create(classA.prototype);
        classB.prototype.constructor = classB;

        return classB;
    }]);
```

---

Now I read that for perfect usage of browserify I have to split my modules into separate files and use an `index.js` to require the parts of this module:

```
var angular = require("angular");

module.exports = angular.module("moduleAB", [])
    .factory("factoryA", require("./factoryA"))
    .factory("factoryB", require("./factoryB"));
```

---

So far, so good. Now I need files for factory A and B. But what's the best way to implement these and preserve DI? Should I write something like (`factoryA.js`):

```
module.exports = ["$window", function(wndw) {
    return function classA (a, b) {
        //...
    };
}];
```

And (`factoryB.js`):

```
module.exports = ["factoryA", function(factoryA) {
    //...
}];
```

---

Or is it better to do (`factoryB.js`):

```
var factoryA = require("./factoryA");

module.exports = [function() {
    //...
}];
```

---

Or (`factoryB.js`):

```
module.exports = [require("./factoryA"), function(factoryA) {
    //...
}];
```

---

It's important that after minification DI still works :)

Comment: I too am looking for more insight into this..

Comment: How to pass params into factoryB? MyController.prototype = new factoryB(this, myObject)